# When a value of a polynomial over $\mathbb Z$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

For which values of $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ the polynomial $16x^3-24x+9$ is a perfect square?

I don't know if this question has a solution, but Wolfram Alpha says that the answer is $x=0$ ([click](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16x%5E3-24x%2b9=y%5E2)), even if $x=1$ is a solution too. Does Wolfram just give some solutions and not all?

Anyway, if Wolfram can give some solutions, I think there is a general method to manage this kind of problem (at least with a third degree polynomial). So, the main question of this message is:

**For which values of** $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ **the polynomial** $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ **is a perfect square?**

Obviously there is not a general answer to the question, but I would like to know which techniques may be usefull to approach the problem.

For example, if $\deg p(x)=2$ sometimes we can solve a Pell's equation, or if $2\mid\deg p(x)$ sometimes the "put between two squares" method may work. Any other methods?

Answer (score 1):

This is an elliptic curve $16x^3-24x+9=y^2$ and you are looking for the integer points.

I don't know how it works in general but there are algorithms.

See [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/15986/5506)

- A- Pethö, H.-G. Zimmer, J. Gebel, E. Herrmann, Computing all S-integral points on elliptic curves, Math. Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 127 (1999), No.3, 383-402
- R.J. Stroeker, N. Tzanakis, Computing all integer solutions of a genus 1 equation Math. Comput. 72 (2003), No. 244, 1917-1933

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for integer points on an elliptic curve. There's a vast literature. One starting point is [Integral points on an elliptic curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32847/integral-points-on-an-elliptic-curve)