# Two variables Diophantine equation $x^3 - 2y^2 =54$

Tags: number-theory

How  can  we  solve  $x^3 - 2y^2 =54$  Diophantine  equation  in  natural  numbers? Modular  arithmetic  method  is  not  useful  maybe?

Comment: Try modulo with $n$ such that $\phi(n)=$lcm$(2,3)$

Comment: i am  not  number  theorist  i  have  no  idea  on  elliptic  curves. I  try  to  solve  elementary  way. But  i shared  because  i  thought  that  maybe  i  didnt  see  important secret  in  the  problem

Comment: No secrets in the theory of elliptic curves: compare with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703137/cubic-diophantine-equation, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669620/a-cubic-diophantine-equation-in-two-variables, etc.

Comment: no  i  mean  "trick" to  solve  the  problem  for  examples how  we  get  a quick  contradiction  and  to  show  unique  solution  (6,9)?

Comment: The fact that the ring of the Eisenstein integers is a UFD leads to a solution, too.

Answer (score 3):

Since $x$ must be even, $x=2z$, we have:
$$ 4z^3- y^2 = 27 \tag{1}$$
or:
$$z^3 = \frac{y+3\sqrt{-3}}{2}\cdot\frac{y-3\sqrt{-3}}{2}=w\cdot\overline{w},\tag{2}$$
where $w$ lies in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$, that is a UFD.
 This implies that, if $w$ and $\overline{w}$ are coprime, $w=\frac{y-1}{2}+3\omega$ must be a cube in the Eisenstein integers $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ (notice that $y$ must be odd, so $\frac{y-1}{2}\in\mathbb{Z}$), but:
$$ (a+b\omega)^3 = a^3+3a^2 b\omega + 3ab^2\omega^2 +b^3 = (a^3+b^3-3ab^2)+3ab(a-b)\omega\tag{3}$$
and $3ab(a-b)=3$ has no integer solutions. The only possibility left is that $w=\sqrt{-3} u^3$ and $\overline{w}= -3v^3$ with $\gcd(u,v)=1$. This happens for $(x,y)=(6,9)$.

Comment: what  about  (6,9)?

Comment: There was a flaw in my original argument since I assumed that $w$ and $\overline{w}$ must be coprime in $Z[\omega]$, but there is an extra case, the one for which $w=\sqrt{-3}u^3$ and $\overline{w}=-3 v^3$ with $\gcd(u,v)=1$. Now fixed.

Comment: This is the only extra case since $w-\overline{w}=3\sqrt{-3}$.