# Find solution in integers of $x^3+x-y^2=1$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

> Find integers $x$ and $y$ such that
>   $$x^3+x-y^2=1.$$

My try:

$$x^3+x-y^2=1 \implies x^3+x-1=y^2.$$

Now, when $x^3+x-1$ is a perfect square?

Comment: hint: left hand side is even number , so $y^2+1$ muse be even $\to y $ must be odd number .

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, using the unique factorisation over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\text{i}]$ of Gaussian integers, this question is equivalent to finding $u,\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}[\text{i}]$ such that $\text{Im}(u\alpha\beta)=1$ and $\alpha\bar{\beta}-u\bar{u}=\text{i}$.  (That is, $x=u\bar{u}$ and $y=u\alpha\beta-\text{i}$.)  I expect an infinite family of solutions.

Comment: Also $x, y$ has to be mutual prime

Comment: I find $(1,1), (2,3), (13,47)$ as small solutions

Comment: I've wrote a computer program to find solutions. For $x \lt 10000000000$ the solutions are: (1,1) (2, 3) (13, 47), (5112308218, 1226294255). I think @Batominovski is right, there might be an infinite family of solutions.

Comment: @EugenCovaci I obtain $5112308218^3+5112308218-1=133613729946263529798154844449 $, but $1226294255^2=1503797599846005025$, so there must be a mistake.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/703220/133781

Answer (score 3):

The elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+x-1$ has only finitely many integral points, according to the magma online calculator - see [here at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52979/integer-points-on-the-elliptic-curve-y2-x317), namely the points
$$
(x,y)=(1,\pm 1),(2,\pm3),(13,\pm 47).
$$

Comment: This might be useful too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32847/integral-points-on-an-elliptic-curve

Comment: @Xam Yes, indeed! My comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703137/cubic-diophantine-equation) points to the same link.