# Find all primes $p$ such that $ p^3-4p+9 $ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all primes $p$ such that  $ p^3-4p+9 $ is a perfect square.

I tried a few different values for $p$, namely $2,3,5,7,$ and $11$. The prime $p =2,7,11$ all worked but $p =13$ didn't so it makes me wonder. How can I find all primes such that it is a perfect square?

EDIT: it turns out this is problem P25 in post number #63 at http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3h1171106p5665470

Comment: If $p^3-4p+9 = n^2$ then $p^3-4p = n^2-9$, i.e. $(p-2)p(p+2) = (n-3)(n+3)$. I'm not sure if this helps, but it might be a good place to start.

Comment: A small beginning: $p^3-4p+9$ is always divisible by three. But it is divisible by nine only when $p\equiv\pm2\pmod9$. This rules out primes not satisfying that congruence.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen   2   sqrt  3;
7   sqrt  18;
11   sqrt  36;
646   sqrt  16419

Comment: Also sprach Mathematica: Those three are the only primes that work among the 10000 smallest primes.

Comment: That and $646$ are all $p$ values up to $10,000,000$

Comment: John, what is the source of the problem?

Comment: @Myself , I like to  check these things without restricting the variable to be prime. Sometimes that condition is a deliberate red herring to disguise the real techniques for dealing with the problem.

Comment: If everything else fails, somebody somewhere can tell the integer points on the elliptic curve
$$y^2=x^3-4x+9.$$ In other words, I am joining in Will Jagy's camp suspecting that primeness of $p$ may not be the key. The use of silicone is described [in this MO answer](http://mathoverflow.net/q/6676/15503). See also [this thread in MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/32847/11619).

Comment: @WillJagy A good point! Although I feel like this is a problem from contest mathematics, where the prime condition is necessary to have an elementary solution. (And the full problem would be easy prey for the wielder of mightier weapons from the realm of elliptic curves.)

Comment: @Myself right, I am fiddling with $p$ prime, there may be a trick. Nope, seems circular. People should identify the source

Comment: @WillJagy I got this question from someone else but it was related to competition math.

Comment: Ok So I cheated a bit I asked Sage nicely for integral points, this is the list [(-2 : 3 : 1),  (0 : 3 : 1),  (2 : 3 : 1),  (7 : 18 : 1),  (11 : 36 : 1),  (646 : 16419 : 1)]. So only 2, 7, 11, as expected...

Comment: @Myself, a neighbor recently installed Sage for me on my home computer; what would be the command(s) for this?

Comment: It's: E = EllipticCurve([0,0,0,-4,9]); E.integral_points() (It is actually described by Sage developer William Stein in the link that Jyrki gave above.)

Comment: @Myself thank you; it works, and I can get detail from the link. I wrote to Stein at some point, he suggested an online calculator version. I couldn't get anywhere with that, and my neighbor from Finland is a sysadmin type. He installed it, and it was clear from what he had to go through on my machine that I would not have been able to do that myself, no matter who I had on telephone helping.

Comment: @WillJagy I must solve this question without a computer.

Comment: @JohnRyan , you have not given us much reason to care. Nothing about your background, nothing of any importance about the problem.

Comment: @WillJagy Have you given https://cloud.sagemath.com/ a chance? It is a lot better than the old notebook.

Comment: It was just a problem a friend gave me to solve it, so I didn't think it was going to be so hard.

Comment: @Myself, I just could not get it to work at all. Usually my friend Dmitry from grad school days helps me install things, guiding me by telephone.  I can use the online calculator for Magma. Between them, I can get the full genus of a positive ternary quadratic form with integer coefficients, including spinor genera, and confirm with the mass formula on Sage.

Comment: @JohnRyan , I see lots of questions here on MSE "given by friends." You never know how careful the friend was in describing the problem, and this way we have no idea what background ought to be used in solving the problem. Get your friend to tell you the answer, in any case the exact source of the problem.

Comment: @WillJagy Here is the exact source of the problem: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u182287h1171106p5665470

Comment: A related question: it seems that $m^4 + 24m +16$ is a square only when $m=3$ (I checked up to $m = 50000000$). Arrive at that by solving for $p$ in the equation $p^3 - 4p + 9 = (mp + 3)^2$ (there is also the case of $mp-3$ I suppose.

Comment: @JohnRyan Evidently P25 at the current end of that thread, by someone you have never met.

Comment: @WillJagy-What you wanted to say is the following I am providing below: (i)For p=2,n=3 as 8-8+9=9,(ii)For p=7,n=18 as 343-28+9=324,and For p=646,n=16419 as 269586136-2584+9=269583561

Answer (score 17):

If $p^3-4p+9=n^2$ then $n^2\equiv 9 \pmod{p}$ and $\pm n \equiv 3 \pmod{p}$ since $n^2-9\equiv 0$ can only have two roots modulo a prime.

By choosing the appropriate sign we can write
$$
\begin{align}
n^2=(-n)^2 &= (kp+3)^2 \\
p^3-4p+9 &= k^2p^2+6kp+9 \\
0 &= p^2-k^2p-(6k+4) \\
p & = \frac{k^2\pm \sqrt{k^4+24k+16}}{2}
\end{align}
$$
where we used $p\ne 0$ since it's a prime. This can only have an integer solution for $p$ when $k^4+24k+16$ is a square (as @tkr suggested in the comments).
But
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
(k^2-1)^2 = k^4-2k^2+1 < k^4+24k+16<(k^2)^2 & \text{if }k<-11 \\
(k^2)^2 < k^4+24k+16< k^4+2k^2+1 =(k^2+1)^2 & \text{if }k>12
\end{array}
$$
so if $k<-11$ or $k>12$ then $k^4+24k+16$ lies between two squares and hence is not a square. This leaves 24 values to check, which you could do by hand. It leads to solutions when $k=-3,0,3$ which give integral values for $p$ of $-2,2,7,11$, of which only $2,7,11$ would normally be considered prime.

Comment: I got to your $ p^2-k^2p-(6k+4) = 0$ and solved for $k$ with the quadratic formula, but did not think to solve for $p$ with the quadratic formula, which is what does the job.

Comment: Anyway, well done, and you also posting on AOPS is the right outcome.

Comment: Here is a less involved solution on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h317329p1706636).

Answer (score 0):

Zander's solution is nice, but there might be a way to reduce the number of cases to check.
when $k\leq -6$ or $k\geq 7$
$(k^2-2)^2<k^4+24k+16<(k^2+2)^2$
but $k^4+24k+16=k^4,(k^2-1)^2,(k^2+1)^2$ don't have solutions. (compare parity for $(k^2-1)^2$ and $(k^2+1)^2$)
so $-5\leq k\leq 6$
also observe 3|k. if not, $k^4+24k+16\equiv 2\pmod3$ , which is not a square.
now $k\in\{-3,0,3,6\}$ , of which 3 out of the 4 cases yield solutions.

question is from turkey NMO 2009, 2nd round, q1:
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h364542