# $y^2 = x^3 + d$ . $d$ square free integer, finite integer solution how to prove.

Tags: number-theory

Fix a square-free integer $d > 1$, and assume that Z[√d] satisfies
the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Show that the equation
$y^2 = x^3 + d$ has only finitely many integral solutions.

Reference: An introduction to number theory. Graham Everest.
Exercise 2.15

Comment: Mordell equations are related.

Answer (score 1):

The solution follows from the material in this section easily, imitating the proof of Theorem 2.11, and Theorem 2.12. Also Siegel's Theorem - Theorem 2.13 is in the book. This solves such problems in general. In fact,
Carl Ludwig Siegel proved that a non-singular plane cubic equation has only finitely many integral solutions. References on this site:

[Integral points on an elliptic curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32847/integral-points-on-an-elliptic-curve)

[Effective proofs of Siegel's theorem using arithmetic geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33281/effective-proofs-of-siegels-theorem-using-arithmetic-geometry)

Furthermore there is Terry Tao's [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/siegels-theorem-on-integral-points/).

Comment: I tried to prove that y+√d,y-√d are co-primes, by using the gcd of them, and so come to prove that x^3 is odd, by assuming it is even and taking mod 8.
Then y^2=d mod 8 and so because of the square, d must be either 0 or 1 or 4.
When testing 0 or 4 I came to contradiction with d a square free, but when I come to test d = 1 mod 8, I don’t know how to come to a contradiction.