# Algorithm for diophantine equation

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, diophantine-equations

From p. 38 of Richard Hodel's *An Introduction to Mathematical Logic*,

"Construct an algorithm that, given an integer $a$, decides in a finite number of steps whether the equation $x^2+y^3-a=0$ has a solution in integers."

I don't see how to place any bound on $x$ or $y$ in terms of $a$, and given the nature of the text I don't think Hodel was expecting any heavy-duty number theory.

POSTSCRIPT: It seems most likely that Hodel meant "a solution in POSITIVE integers", as I don't think the author was expecting familiarity with the  bound mentioned by Qiaochu.

Comment: I also don't see any easy argument here. Here is a hard one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32903/232

Comment: Is there anything in the original text to suggest that $y>-1$?

Comment: Thank you, Qiaochu; Old Peter, there was no mention of positivity. I think that there was simply a misprint in the original text as no one has seen an obvious elementary method.

Comment: I still have a nagging doubt that the question might have been correct, and we are missing something obvious. I've searched for $a$ from $-1000$ to $1000$ with $x=0$ to $75000$ and $y=-8255$ to $10$. Indeed, I've found lots of $a$ values that don't show a solution. However, the minimal results such as $46710^2+(-1297)^3=-973$ give me little confidence.

Answer (score -1):

The above equation is shown below:

$$x^2+y^3-a=0  \tag1\label1$$

Consider restricting value of $a$ to $a=(x+y)^2$ then, the solution to equation \eqref{1} above is given below:

\begin{align}
x &= \frac{6k^2-7k+2}{k^2} \\
y &= \frac{-3k^2+2k}{k^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: This is completely non-sensical.  The question explicitly asks for integer solutions for an arbitrary integer $a$.