# Find integral solutions of a elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, computer-algebra-systems

I want to find the integral points of the following equation
$$y^{2}=x^{3}-219x+1652$$

But, I don't have any computational program.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32847/11619) but not really helpful to this question. Basically trying to pre-empt unschooled critics from yelling "no effort shown" (and that was the first google hit),

Comment: OTOH [this question from MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/282762/15503) may have something that actually helps.

Comment: In the range $[-10^6,10^8]$, the polynomial $x^3-219x+1652$ does not give a perfect square or $0$ or $1$. So, there might be no integer solution.

Comment: Still no solution upto $x=10^9$

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter.

Comment: According to MAGMA-calculator, there are no integral solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There are NO rational points never mind integer ones.

Using Pari/GP's elltors(), the curve has no finite torsion points and Denis Simon's ellrank() code states that the rank = 0.

This gives the result.