# Integer solution of $x^3 - x + 9 = 5 y^2$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Prove/disprove that $x^3 - x + 9 = 5 y^2 $ has integer solution. i.e) There doesn't exist $x,y$ in integers satisfying above equation.

I tried using congruence and get if solution exist then $x$ should be congruent to $2\pmod{5}$. But after that, I tried something but I haven't get any conclusion. Please give me a hint if the statement is true.

Comment: No square of an integer can be $2 \pmod 5$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @metamorphy thanks for pointing out !

Comment: It does have a rational solution, $x=\frac {4}{5},y=\frac{33}{25}$.

Comment: @S.Dolan thanks for remarks But question is about integers

Comment: Cloud JR, @S.Dolan's discovery is very important. It implies that modulo any integer not a multiple of five there are integer solutions (because $5$ and hence also $25$ have a modular inverse). This strongly suggests that we may need tools other than modular arithmetic to settle this.

Comment: Which brings me to request for the source of the quesion. Is there a reason to believe that tools lesser than those developed to find integer points on elliptic curves are sufficient here?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen.@S.Dolan I haven't know this before , my apologies.

Comment: @jyrki lahtonten , It was in exercise of notes sum of two square. But I have no idea what sum of square have anything to do with this. Btw, this is not my homework as the due date ends a month before. I haven't solve it. So now I am trying but i think It won't work , that's why I ask here

Comment: Is your question actually $x^2-x+9=5y^2$?

Comment: No it's x^3.  Not squared, I checked it .

Comment: Can you attach the notes "sum of two squares" if it is a PDF? Else, take a photo of the problem, and of the pages coresponding to the chapter.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/a/iisertvm.ac.in/file/d/13k5w7mboGYxpY4QgKxWmMq1hZ_MPPuPO/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The substitution $U=5x, V=25y$ turns this equation into that of an elliptic curve with the short Weierstrass form
$$
U^3-25U+1125=V^2.
$$
According to [its LMFDB entry](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/218300/e/1) the integer points on this elliptic curve are $(U,V)=(4,\pm33)$

There are no solutions with $V$ a multiple of $25$, so the original equation has no integer solutions.

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32847/11619) for more information and sources.

Comment: Bailing out with a table look-up. I am not knowledgeable enough to tell whether an elementary argument giving all the integer points of this curve exists.

Answer (score 2):

More of a comment, but there are too many already. Having read all the comments, it seems to me a strong possibility that the equation whoever produced the pdf problem sheet intended to set was $$x^2-x+9=5y^2$$

Put another way, the OP insists his Q has $x^3$, but I strongly suspect the Q whoever set the problem wanted him to solve had $x^2$, so it might be worth giving a quick answer to that. @JyrkiLahtonen has already given an excellent answer to the Q as the OP has given it. I hope it has piqued his curiosity for delights to come ...

So completing the square: $$(x-1/2)^2+35/4=5y^2$$ Multiplying by 4 and rearranging: $$5(2y)^2-(2x-1)^2=35$$

Now $2x-1$ must be divisible by 5, so writing it as $5z$ and $2y$ as $w$ we get $$w^2-5z^2=7$$ which is a standard Pell equation. They are discussed endlessly on this site, and it is not hard to show that it has no solution in integers, and *a fortiori* no solution with $w$ even and $z$ odd).