# Smallest Integer Solution of an Elliptic Curve

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

**Description:** An elliptic curve is defined as $y^2=x^3+ax^2+b$, here, $a, b$ are integers and $(x',y')$ is the point on curve with smallest possible integers coordinate of the elliptic curve.

**Question:** Is there any inequality regarding integer coefficient $a, b$ and the $x',y'$?

Comment: $x',y'$ needn't exist.

Comment: @Wojowu what is the necessary and sufficient condition for the existence?

Comment: I doubt any sensible criteria in terms of $a,b$ exist. The only thing that comes to my mind is that if the curve has a nontrivial torsion point, then by Nagell-Lutz it has integer coordinates.

Comment: @Wojowu the curve I am working  on, atleast has an integer solution, can we infer the there are other integer solutions?

Comment: That said, if we assume there *does* exist a point on the elliptic curve, you can get an explicit upper bound from a result of Baker mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32903/127263)

Comment: If $(x,y)$ is an integer solution and $y\neq 0$, then $(x,-y)$ is another solution. You cannot conclude there are other ones - there are curves with only two integer points like that. In fact, an elliptic curve will always have finitely many points.

Comment: @Wojowu thanks for your help.